# Should I use remember with animateDpAsState?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The Code A is from the official sample code [here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-basics#10).

I know that in order to preserve state across recompositions, remember the mutable state using remember.

I think that the code `val extraPadding by animateDpAsState(...)` should be  `val extraPadding by remember { animateDpAsState(...) }`, is it right?

BTW, `val extraPadding by remember { animateDpAsState(...) }` will cause the error

> Composable calls are not allowed inside the calculation parameter of inline fun  remember(calculation: () -> TypeVariable(T)): TypeVariable(T)

**Code A**

```
@Composable
private fun Greeting(name: String) {

    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val extraPadding by animateDpAsState(                  //Should I add remember
        if (expanded) 48.dp else 0.dp
    ) 

    Surface(
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 4.dp, horizontal = 8.dp)
    ) {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(24.dp)) {
            Column(modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(bottom = extraPadding)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Hello, ")
                Text(text = name)
            }
            OutlinedButton(
                onClick = { expanded = !expanded }
            ) {
                Text(if (expanded) "Show less" else "Show more")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you shouldn't. This function is marked with `@Composable` so it should be used directly in the view builder.

[`animateDpAsState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/animation/core/package-summary?hl=ko#animateDpAsState(androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.animation.core.AnimationSpec,kotlin.Function1)) will calculate its value depending on `targetValue` on each recomposition.

If you check it source code you'll see, that it uses `remember` inside, that's why it's marked with `@Composable`, and that's why you shouldn't bother about remembering some values manually.

Comment: How can one then remember the state of the animation? I'm going through the codelab and they do not show an example of this. 

The [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-basics#10) says `You could save this data with rememberSaveable if it were a requirement, but we are keeping the example simple.`

Comment: @FlashspeedIfe this codelab quote talks about `expanded` variable, not about `animateDpAsState`

Comment: Yes but as the codelab also talks about state I would have expected there to be some info on how to remember the state of animateDpAsState.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes across this in the future, instead of attempting to remember the animateDpAsState it would be better to  remember the expansion state.  Because in this case we're trying to remember the state in an item of a list we use rememberSaveable:

```
var expanded by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
```

A very similar case of storing indexes across list items is shown in the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#item-keys)